# Selecting with preference in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000, no-duplicates

I have a table in SQL Server 2000 with data similar to the following:

```
ReferenceNumber    ReferenceValue
00001              Not assigned
00002              Not assigned
00002              ABCDE
```

in which each ReferenceNumber can appear multiple times in the table, either with a ReferenceValue of 'Not assigned' or a true ReferenceValue.

I want to dump the data into a cleaned-up table with only one row per ReferenceNumber and a true ReferenceValue if it exists, or 'Not assigned' if there are no true ReferenceValues.

I can see how to do it with two queries:

```
SELECT TOP 1 ReferenceNumber, ReferenceValue
INTO clean
FROM duplicates
WHERE ReferenceValue <> 'Not assigned'

INSERT INTO clean(ReferenceNumber, ReferenceValue)
SELECT TOP 1 ReferenceNumber, ReferenceValue
WHERE ReferenceValue = 'Not assigned' 
AND ReferenceNumber NOT IN (SELECT ReferenceNumber FROM clean)
```

but I'm thinking there must be a better way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT 
  ReferenceNumber
, ReferenceValue = ISNULL(MAX(NULLIF(ReferenceValue,'Not assigned')),'Not assigned')
INTO Table1_Clean
FROM Table1
GROUP BY
  ReferenceNumber
```

MAX() ignores NULLs, so convert whatever you don't want to NULL first, then MAX(), then convert NULLs back to a dummy value.

One pass, in-line, can't get much more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

For SQL SERVER 2000, this is probably easiest. First clause = "real" values, second clause where not found in first clause. And an extension of your idea.

```
SELECT d2.ReferenceNumber, d2.ReferenceValue
FROM duplicates d2
WHERE d2.ReferenceValue <> 'Not assigned'
UNION ALL
SELECT d1.ReferenceNumber, d1.ReferenceValue
FROM duplicates d1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
         FROM duplicates d2
         WHERE d2.ReferenceNumber = d1.ReferenceNumber AND
                 d2.ReferenceValue <> 'Not assigned')
```

However, what criteria do you want to tie break between "true" reference values? or just pick one?

Comment: For this specific problem, a ReferenceNumber will either have 'Not assigned' or have a unique ReferenceValue, so there's no issue with ties.

Comment: @taserian: removed my aggregate

Comment: I kept the aggregate, since even though a RefNumber can have one true RefValue, that RefNumber-RefValue pair can appear multiple times in the table.

Comment: This is three reads and a self-join, where you only need one read and no joins.

Comment: @gbn: did you have parallel execution in mind when you suggested this method?

Comment: @Peter: no. Just for clarity. I understand your solution (I upvoted) but my solution is hopefully more clear and obvious.

Comment: @gbn: do you think this would this use parallel reads? I think it might for the reads and joins, but I have a blind spot for parallelism and don't really know how to gauge the relative cost vs. an intermediate spool. Remus pointed out the possibility here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618560/select-and-merge-rows-in-a-table-in-sql-stored-procedure/1618656#1618656. I was certain before, not so certain now.

Comment: @Peter: heck. I don't know. However, spooling can be expensive and often one of the hardest things to tune away. I guess "it depends": indexes, number of rows, does cost meet parallel threshold etc.